# Microsoft CAL when using Outlook and Googls Apps Sync Tool

Tags: outlook, licensing, g-suite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We just migrated our email system to Google Apps. Many users still prefer to use Outlook and we're quite happy with the new Sync Tool from Google.
Legally wise, is it necessary to have Client Access License for each user ?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What CAL are you referring to? Clearly if the users are still connecting up to a Windows domain/file server then a Windows CAL will still be needed. If you've migrated from an Exchange system then you'll no longer need the Exchange CALs if you're not using any of its features.

As TomTom says though - you'll still need to have the base Windows OS licence on each machine as well as an Outlook licence.

Comment: Each user has:
1 windows server CAL (ie, for connecting to the file server)
1 MS windows XP license
1 MS Office license

So I guess this is enough !
I was referring to the Exchange CAL.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a CAL. WHat you do need is:

- Obviously a valid WIndows license ;)
- a license for Outlook, which you most likely have as part of some office packet.

Comment: Then you are done already. Nothing else needed.